# Implement FOR Loop with length function in single command in R

Tags: r

Is there a quick way to implement the following code in R, in a single command

```
vec = 0
for(i in 1:3){
 vec = vec + length((2^(i-1)):(2^i-1))
}
vec
[1] 7
```

Somewhere I've seen that we can use apply or apply functions to do that, but I cannot find it somewhere.

Comment: If you are interested in this problem in particular, you can just use mathematics and simplify this to `2^3 - 1`. This is a telescoping series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a oneliner that does the same.

```
sum(sapply(1:3, function(i) length((2^(i-1)):(2^i-1))))
```